# Webscraping using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the information from the webpage. I would like to open the links which are in the webpage and save the data inside of it. For that i am using python beautifulsoup package. Please help me in opening the internal links from the webpage. My code is followed :

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib
 r = urllib.urlopen('http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/ciren/CaseForm.aspx?      xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=317310129').read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
 print type(soup)
 all_links = soup.find_all("a")
 for link in all_links:
    print link.get("href")  
    print "\n"
```

Here i am printing the data but how to open the link and get the info from those links. after printing i am getting info as below :

```
SearchForm.aspx?ClearSearch


ListForm.aspx


CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=317310129&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true


javascript:parent.myPrintAll(317310129,'10-149','','v 1.0.112008','CIREN','CIREN was established in 1996 and is a multi-center research program involving a collaboration of clinicians and engineers in academia, industry, and government. Level 1 Trauma Centers are linked together through a computer network associated with this research program. Each Center collects detailed crash and medical data on approximately 50 motor vehicle crashes per year. After the necessary coding and quality control takes place, the information is added to a database on the computer network linking the centers. The CIREN database consists of multiple discrete fields of data concerning these crashes, including crash reconstruction and medical injury profiles. Personal and location identifiers and highly sensitive medical information have been removed from the public files to protect patient confidentiality.');


javascript:parent.myPrint(317310129,'10-149','CIREN');


javascript:parent.ShowXML(317310129,'',317310129,true);


javascript:parent.ShowXSD('../XSD/Ciren2013.xsd','',true);
Please help me on this issue.
```

Comment: There are relative links, that would have to be converted into absolute links by appending them to the base url: "http://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/ciren/". The others are javascript. If you want to scrape a page that uses javascript maybe you need to find a different tool like selenium that actually runs javascript.

Comment: I see mainly JavaScript not URLs

Comment: What are you actually trying to get> You hardly want every link on that page.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham    I am trying to open the links inside a webpage and save the info in that link page. when i tried with beautifulsoup internal link data is coming as javscript url. is there any way i can concert those javascript data to actual link? suggest me any other way to do this.

Comment: Yes but what exactly do you want to download?

Comment: the website has a text and images-only option. Perhaps you'd be better of scraping on that. The link you posted has text and images-only here https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/ciren/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=317310129&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true

Comment: @jlaur ... yes the website contains only text and images. link is "https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618"  here if we traverse Vehicle 1--> Images-->Front.  we have 3 images is there a way to download them locally.    when I try to get src info of image it gave me as "src="GetBinary.aspx?Image&amp;ImageID=247247008&amp;CaseID=773013618&amp;Version=0">"  Please help me on this